# selector with two property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop unto all the input that has a required attribute and which value is empty.

I tried this

```
$("input[required][value='']").each(function(){
    alert("s"); 
});
```

but unfortunately, not working. Any help, ideas?

Comment: Can you add your _complete_ code, a jsfiddle demo will help solve the problem quickly

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking each required input for empty value with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409429/checking-each-required-input-for-empty-value-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
$("input[required]").filter(function(){
   return $(this).val().length === 0;
}).each(function(){
    alert("s"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as it is, just put it inside `$(function()...` as shown below.

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[required][value='']").each(function(){
     alert("s"); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="" required>
<input value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$("input[required][value='']").each(function)({
    alert("s"); 
});
```